# Magento 2.3.5 p1 latest?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Am i on the latest version of Magento? We are on 235p1 and version is community. Are there critical patches available?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, as per Magento's official release calendar (https://devdocs.magento.com/release/), in less than a month, the latest version will be **2.3.7** for 2.3.x and **2.4.2-p1** for 2.4.x.

Answer (score 0):

You are not on the latest version. The current latest version of Magento 2 is 2.4.2 released on 31st March 2021.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html

In Magento 2.3 current latest version is 2.3.6
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html